# find coordinates of rotated sigmoidal curve

Tags: polynomials, analytic-geometry

Given the equation for sigmoidal function and the coordinates of point A (see fig.),
how can I find the coordinates (blue points) for a rotated curve passing through a point A? 
Please see the attached figure.[image]

**My current thoughts**:
In the case of two lines, one could just easily find an angle (θ) between two lines and get the new coordinates with the formula on figure 2. 
Maybe in the case of two sigmoidal curves, it is also possible to find an angle between them and then rotate each point individually by this angle.

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @TheCount , please consider the updated question.

Comment: Looks good now. Your intuition is absolutely correct. Hint: The general shape of your sigmoid is already fixed, so you need only find two points on the remaining curve. If your left asymptote is at $y=20$, and you appear to want to rotate about that point, so there's one, and you know $A$.

Comment: There is something wrong with your equation for $y$ as it is plain that at $x=0, y=55$. Please provide the correct information so we can proceed with an answer